# Reference a Perl Module that creates a hash in another Perl Module file that sets the hash equal to that hash

Tags: perl, hash, package, perl-module, exporter

I have 2 perlmodule files (.pm). `File_A.pm` is located on `/some/dir/here/File_A.pm`. I have a `File_B.pm` located on `/some/other/dir/File_B.pm`.

`File_B.pm` will set its `my %machines` hash equal to `/some/dir/here/File_A.pm`'s `%machines` if `File_A.pm` is readable using `if (-r '/some/dir/here/File_A.pm')` else it will use a standard hash defined within `File_B.pm` as `my %machines = ()`.

I have tried the code below

However, this is not working for me.

```
package some::other::dir::File_B;
use strict;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT $VERSION);
use Cwd;
use some::dir::File_A;

use Exporter;
$VERSION = 1.0;
@ISA     = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT =
  qw(getMachines printMachines getMachineAttributes printMachineAttributes);

if(-r '/some/dir/here/File_A.pm'){
    my %machines = do q{/some/dir/here/File_A.pm};
else{
 my %machines = (  
    "some.fqdn.com" => {
    role        => ["someRole"],
    environment => "test",
    location    => "USA",
    os          => "Ubuntu",},
    )
}
###################################
#I have getMachines, printMachines, getMachineAtrributes, and
#printMachineAttributes below here in my code
####################################
```

I am expecting the logic to use the File_A.pm my %machines hash if it is readable and if not use the backup my %machines hash in case the File_A.pm somehow becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a lexical variable defined with [my](http://p3rl.org/my) spans from the declaration to the end of the enclosing block. The first `my %machines` doesn't survive the "then" block, the second one disappears at the end of the "else" block.

Note that if File_A is writable by a malicious user, they can insert any code into it. It's safer to use an INI file, or JSON, YAML, XML, or whatever to populate the hash.

Comment: Hmm that is an angle I hadn't considered. If I go with an XML file externally. How would I reference it and parse it into a perl hash?

Comment: You can ask a new question as, well, a new question :-)

Comment: Ok, turning make to my original post. My question is do loop the correct way to set the %machines hash equal to an external pm's %machine hash?

Comment: Note that if a malicious user can create the Perl module, they can also likely create a file in whatever format you then use. There's no additional safety in some other format.

Comment: Well, an INI file can't contain code, unlike a `.pm`.